# Distribute Xamarin IOS gave an error required Mac connection

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, cross-platform, visual-studio-2019

I'm developing iOS app using Visual Studio 2019 Community on Windows.
I don't have a mac, so I'm using MacinCloud.com.
I already paid for Apple Developer fee.

I have successfully build and archieve the project.
But I have trouble creating IPA file or publishing to App Store.
It always give error **A connection to a Mac is required in order to continue**.
[Error while creating IPA file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWaSc.jpg)

My connection with MacinCloud.com is not a problem, since I have successfully archieve the project.

Has anyone ever encounter with this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Hmm Thats a little confusing. Are you also able to build onto your Mac simulator from your Visual studio for windows, to make sure there is no connection issue? You only get that error once you archive your project. The archive typically creates an XCode archive file that you can alternatively open using XCode on your Mac computer and then distribute it from there.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of strange. I was able to distribute using XCode. Maybe there is a bug from Visual Studio 2019.
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Did you follow these instructions to pair your Mac to your windows? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/

Comment: Yes, I did. I had successfully archieve the project. My problem is that I can not publish it to App Store using Visual Studio 2019 from my Windows. So I just publish it from Xcode on Mac at MacinCloud.com